# Why do disjunction and conjunction in words need parenthesis?

Tags: ruby, argument-passing

Disjunction and conjunction in words (`or`, `and`) in argument position require additional parentheses, as opposed to `||`, `&&`.

```
def foo _; end

foo(1 || 2) # => Good
foo(1 or 2) # => Syntax error
foo((1 or 2)) # => Good

foo(1 && 2) # => Good
foo(1 and 2) # => Syntax error
foo((1 and 2)) # => Good
```

Why do they need additional parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because logical composition operators `and` and `or` have lower [precedence](http://romhack.wikia.com/wiki/Ruby_operators#Operator_precedence) than a method's argument list, so the parser fails when another list argument or enclosing parenthesis is not found.

On the other hand logical operators `&&` and `||` have higher precedence so their arguments are evaluated sooner and result of the expression then passed to method as an argument.

Standalone parenthesis change associativity, so `foo (1 or 2)` does work and `1` is passed as a result to `foo` method.

Comment: @sawa Yep, parens enclosing method arguments is a quite different case then parens enforcing associativity of evaluation. For the former, space after method name is disallowed.

Comment: The [Ruby style guide does recommend just saying no to `and` and `or`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or). Be careful with the space trick. If your method then takes 2 arguments the first being the `(1 or 2)` You would need to do `foo (1 or 2),3` `foo (1 or 2,3)` is similarly a syntax error. Also of interest, with a single argument method, you may be inclined to delete the parenthesis yielding different results: `foo 1 or 2` === `foo(1) or 2` ==>  `2` but `foo 1 || 2` === `foo(1 || 2)` ==> `nil`

Comment: @Charlie Good points, just a little nitpick to example with multiple method arguments. The expression `foo (1 or 2,3)` is a bit different to previous examples and unrelated to `foo` method. `(1 or 2,3)` alone is just an invalid expression, ie. `(_, _)` is not a valid constructor in Ruby.